# Restricting mail sending from SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

On a remote database server, hosting databases from a number of different clients, how do I ensure that someone does not send emails using my profile?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to ensure the profile isn't `public` when you assign permissions and access to it.  The stored procedure in the `msdb` database is [`msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_principalprofile_sp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187911.aspx), and this stored proc is what grants permissions for an `msdb` database role or user.

Excerpt taken from BOL on the subject:

> To make a profile public, specify a @principal_id of 0 or a @principal_name of public. A public profile is available to all users in the msdb database, though users must also be a member of DatabaseMailUserRole to execute sp_send_dbmail.

BOL reference on [Creating a Database Mail Private Profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187605.aspx#PrivateProfile).

Comment: ,How about using Policy based management ?